# Using a list of titles, to be used in switch

Tags: c#, .net

I need to have a switch statement that will switch through a list of titles.
Would it be best to have a string[], enum, list, etc?
The list will constant and the values will not change.

And how would I implement an enum that switches through string values?

Comment: of those options, only an enum will work. You can't switch on a string value.

Comment: @Erix You can if it is compile time constant.  Of course, that is `string` and not `string[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `string[]` won't work because you can't `switch` on it and have each case be an element at index *n*.
- `List<string>` won't work for the same reasons
- `enum` is rather standard practice, so I hear.

For an example of what I talk about in the first two instances:

```
switch(l)
{
    case l[0] == "boo":
        break;
}
```

Presents the compiler error:

```
A switch expression or case label must be a bool, char, string, integral, enum, or corresponding nullable type
```

And gladly, as I can't imagine why someone would implement it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Depends. If the titles are simply strings that are not dynamic then go with enum. If the titles are going to have other properties then use an array of title objects. If the number of titles may change you probably want some type of list. If the number of titles will stay the same but the titles might change then I'd just use string[]. But most of the time i've seen switch statements they are used with enums...